# How can I fix connection errors in MacPort's installed MySQL?

Tags: mysql, shell

Yesterday I ran 'sudo port install mysql5' and MacPorts installed it perfectly, but then I couldn't run 'mysql' or 'mysqlstart' (I created the proper aliases for that). The error that appears each time is:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/opt/local/var/run/mysql5/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MacPorts `mysql5` port only includes the client libraries for MySQL.  If you also want to run a local MySQL server, you should install the server port as well:

```
$ sudo port install mysql5-server
```

Answer (score 1):

Check to see if the mysql daemon listener is running and listening on port 3306.  If not, perhaps all you have to do is start it up.